# Get the max value using kotlin-exposed

Tags: java, sql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I want to simulate this query using kotlin exposed framework:

```
SELECT max(episodes.season_number) FROM episodes WHERE episodes.parent_id = 944947
```

I tried the next one query:

```
fun countSeasonsForParentId(id: Int) = transaction {
   EpisodeTable.slice(EpisodeTable.season)
       .select { EpisodeTable.parentId eq id }
       .map { it[EpisodeTable.season] }.maxOrNull()
}
```

But this query just results in:

```
SELECT episodes.season_number FROM episodes WHERE episodes.parent_id = 944947
```

and the max value is selected in the code.

How to perform finding max value on the side of the database and map it to `Int`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried similar query and I believe it fits your need.

The query is:

```
        Reservations
            .slice(Reservations.date.max())
            .select { Reservations.note eq "it" }
            .maxByOrNull { Reservations.date }
```

And it generates SQL query:

```
SELECT MAX(reservations."date") FROM reservations WHERE reservations.note = 'it'
```

Your query can be used as:

```
    EpisodeTable
   .slice(EpisodeTable.season.max())
   .select { EpisodeTable.parentId eq id }
   .maxByOrNull { EpisodeTable.season }
   ?.get(EpisodeTable.season.max())
```

**Alternative, for extracting one value seems more appropriate:**

```
   EpisodeTable
   .slice(EpisodeTable.season.max())
   .select { EpisodeTable.parentId eq id }
   .firstOrNull()
   ?.get(EpisodeTable.season.max())
```

Comment: this type of query returns `ResultRow` but `Int` is required

Comment: You are right, I missed last part - to get the value out of the result row. Try the updated answer please.

Comment: thanks, I only replaced `maxByOrNull()` with `firstOrNull()`

Comment: Agreed, that is much better for extracting one value.